# NextJS API Route does not recognize or parse JSON

Tags: next.js, tsx

I'm experimenting with nextjs+react and can't figure out something extremely trivial - sending and receiving a post request via the internal API: The stringified JSON is not recognized and thus not parsed correctly.

**Client component**

```
const data1 = { key: 'test123' };

const response = await fetch('/api/chat', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
       },
   body: JSON.stringify(data1),
      });
```

**API page (/pages/api/chat.tsx)**

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse): Promise<any> {

    const data = JSON.parse(req.body)
    console.log(data)
}
```

**Error**
The console prints the error:

> pages/api/chat.tsx (10:22) @ parse  ⨯ SyntaxError: "[object Object]"
> is not valid JSON
> at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
> at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/chat.tsx:6:23)

From what I've read, nextjs should understand the body as json because it is set in the headers of the request. However, this does not work.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Next.js automatically parses the `Content-Type` of the `body` parameter. See the [docs here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes#request-helpers).

In your case, simply remove the usage of `JSON.parse` in your api route, e.g.:

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse): Promise<any> {

    const data = req.body
    console.log(data)
}
```